# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') when working with useRef in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import AuthButton from "../components/AuthButton";
import AuthContainer from "../components/AuthContainer";
import AuthInput from "../components/AuthInput";
import { signup } from "../firebase"

function Signup() {
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();

  async function handleSignup() {
    await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
  }

  return (
    <AuthContainer>
      <AuthInput ref={emailRef} placeholder="  email" />
      <AuthInput ref={passwordRef} type="password" placeholder="  password" />
      <AuthInput ref={passwordConfirmRef} type="password" placeholder="  confirm password" />
      <div className="flex justify-center text-lg text-gray-500 pt-2 pb-5">
        {/* <AuthButton text="sign up" /> */}
          <button onClick={handleSignup}>
        {
          <div className="p-1 rounded-full bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 bg-opacity-50 text-center h-8 w-20">
            sign up
          </div>
        }
    </button>
      </div>
    </AuthContainer>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

The above is a component for a Signup page for a web app, and I'm following this video using refs and firebase to work with a button to update the database: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Kv965pA-j8

However, whenever I click the button, I get this error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

```
handleSignup
  11 |  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
  12 | 
  13 |  async function handleSignup() {
> 14 |    await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
     | ^  15 |  }
  16 | 
  17 |  return (
View compiled
▶ 19 stack frames were collapsed.
```

How can I fix this? My original plan had a separate component for the button together, but that wasn't working, so now I'm just trying to get everything to work all in the same component.

AuthInput Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRef } from "react";

const AuthInput = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='pt-2 pb-2 px-20 mx-auto my-auto'>
            <input
                className="rounded-lg focus:outline-none text-lg placeholder-gray-500"
                type={props.type}
                ref = {props.ref}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                // later figure out how to automatically indent the placeholder text and the inputted text
            />
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default AuthInput
```

Comment: Refs must set only to the `DOM` elements, but you set it to  `AuthInput` component props. Share `AuthInput` code

Comment: @VitaliyRayets I edited the question to include the AuthInput code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want throw parent refs to child components you must use `forwardRef` in child. [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Example of correct `AuthInput` component:

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";
const AuthInput = forwardRef(({ ...otherProps }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div className="pt-2 pb-2 px-20 mx-auto my-auto">
      <input
        className="rounded-lg focus:outline-none text-lg placeholder-gray-500"
        type={otherProps.type}
        ref={ref}
        placeholder={otherProps.placeholder}
        // later figure out how to automatically indent the placeholder text and the inputted text
      />
    </div>
  );
});

export default AuthInput;
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem!! Could I ask what the ... does before the otherProps though?

Comment: Rest parameter `...` syntax allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array